# Error from server (Forbidden): Forbidden (user=system:anonymous, verb=get,

Tags: kubernetes

[xueke@master-01 admin]$ kubectl logs nginx-deployment-76bf4969df-999x8
    Error from server (Forbidden): Forbidden (user=system:anonymous, verb=get, resource=nodes, subresource=proxy) ( pods/log nginx-deployment-76bf4969df-999x8)

```
[xueke@master-01 admin]$ kubectl config view
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
    server: https://192.168.0.101:6443
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: admin
  name: kubernetes
current-context: kubernetes
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: admin
  user:
    client-certificate-data: REDACTED
    client-key-data: REDACTED
```

I specified the admin user here
How do I need to modify it?

Comment: Add more about your problem and what are you want to do.

Answer (score 3):

The above error means your apiserver doesn't have the credentials (`kubelet cert and key`) to authenticate the kubelet's log/exec commands and hence the `Forbidden` error message.

You need to provide `--kubelet-client-certificate=<path_to_cert>` and `--kubelet-client-key=<path_to_key>` to your apiserver, this way apiserver authenticate the kubelet with the certficate and key pair.

For more information, have a look at:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/kubelet-authn-authz/

Answer (score 0):

In our case, the error stemmed from Azure services being downgraded because of a bug in DNS resolution, introduced in Ubuntu 18.04.
See [Azure status](https://status.azure.com) and [the technical thread](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1988119). I ran this command to set a fallback DNS address in the nodes:

```bash
az vmss list-instances -g <resourcegroup> -n vmss --query "[].id" --output tsv \
  | az vmss run-command invoke --scripts "echo FallbackDNS=168.63.129.16 >> /etc/systemd/resolved.conf; systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service" --command-id RunShellScript --ids @-
```

Answer (score -2):

That's an RBAC error. The user had no permissions to see logs. If you have a user with cluster-admin permissions you can fix this error with

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding the-boss --user system:anonymous --clusterrole cluster-admin
```

Note: Not a good idea to give an anonymous user cluster-admin role. Will fix the issue though.

Comment: RBAC shouldn't be used for providing anonymous users as cluster-admin access. This could be disastrous.
See following issue for more info https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/55872:

Comment: This is the worst "solution" I've ever seen on stackoverflow. People sometimes just mindlessly copy commands and that's a bad one.