# Jenkins Kubernetes builds fail with Forbidden (user=system:anonymous, verb=get, resource=nodes, subresource=proxy)

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-apiserver, kubernetes-security, kubernetes-jenkins-plugin

**Exec Summary**

Jenkins is running in a Kubernetes cluster just upgrade to 1.19.7 but now jenkins build scripts are failing when running

```
sh "kubectl --kubeconfig ${args.config} config use-context ${args.context}"
```

to give error

```
io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Forbidden (user=system:anonymous, verb=get, resource=nodes, subresource=proxy)
```

but what permissions or roles should I change?

**MORE DETAIL HERE**

Jenkins is running within a Kubernetes cluster, as a master, and it picks up GIT jobs and then creates slave pods which are also supposed to run in the same cluster.   We have a namespace in the cluster called "Jenkins".    As you use Jenkins to creates builds of the microservice applications which are in their own containers, then prompts to have these deployed through the pipeline of test, demo, production.

The cluster has been updated to Kubernetes 1.19.7 using kops.   Everything still deploys, runs and is accessible as normal.   To the user you would not think that there is a problem to the applications which are running internally on the cluster; all are accessible via the browser and PODS show no significant issues.

Jenkins is still accessible (running version 2.278, with Kubernetes plugin 1.29.1, Kubernetes credential 0.8.0, Kubernetes Client API Plugin 4.13.2-1)

I can log into Jenkins, see everything I would normally expect to see

I can use LENS to connect to the cluster and see all the nodes, pods etc as normal.

However, and this is where our problem now lies post upgrading 1.19.7, when a Jenkins job starts it now always fails at the point which it tries to set the kubectl context

We get this error in every build pipeline at the same place...

```
    [Pipeline] load
[Pipeline] { (JenkinsUtil.groovy)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // load
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Set-Up and checks)
[Pipeline] withCredentials
Masking supported pattern matches of $KUBECONFIG or $user or $password
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] container
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
Warning: A secret was passed to "sh" using Groovy String interpolation, which is insecure.
         Affected argument(s) used the following variable(s): [KUBECONFIG, user]
         See https://****.io/redirect/groovy-string-interpolation for details.
java.net.ProtocolException: Expected HTTP 101 response but was '403 Forbidden'
    at okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket.checkResponse(RealWebSocket.java:229)
    at okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket$2.onResponse(RealWebSocket.java:196)
    at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:203)
    at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // container
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] echo
io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Forbidden (user=system:anonymous, verb=get, resource=nodes, subresource=proxy)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // podTemplate
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
[Bitbucket] Notifying commit build result
[Bitbucket] Build result notified
```

Now I presume this is about security....but I'm unsure what to change

I can see that it's using system:anonymous and this may have been restricted in later Kubernetes versions, but I'm unsure how to either supply another user or allow this to work from the Jenkins master node in this namespace.

As we run jenkins and also have jenkins deploy I can see the following service accounts

```
kind: ServiceAccount
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
    name: jenkins
    namespace: jenkins
    selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/jenkins/serviceaccounts/jenkins
    uid: a81a479a-b525-4b01-be39-4445796c6eb1
    resourceVersion: '94146677'
    creationTimestamp: '2020-08-20T13:32:35Z'
    labels:
        app: jenkins-master
        app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
        chart: jenkins-acme-2.278.102
        heritage: Helm
        release: jenkins-acme-v2
    annotations:
        meta.helm.sh/release-name: jenkins-acme-v2
        meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: jenkins
secrets:
    - name: jenkins-token-lqgk5
```

and also

```
kind: ServiceAccount
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: jenkins-deployer
  namespace: jenkins
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/jenkins/serviceaccounts/jenkins-deployer
  uid: 4442ec9b-9cbd-11e9-a350-06cfb66a82f6
  resourceVersion: '2157387'
  creationTimestamp: '2019-07-02T11:33:51Z'
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: >
      {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"ServiceAccount","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"jenkins-deployer","namespace":"jenkins"}}
secrets:
  - name: jenkins-deployer-token-mdfq9
```

And the following roles

jenkins-role

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: >
      {"apiVersion":"rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1","kind":"Role","metadata":{"annotations":{"meta.helm.sh/release-name":"jenkins-acme-v2","meta.helm.sh/release-namespace":"jenkins"},"creationTimestamp":"2020-08-20T13:32:35Z","labels":{"app":"jenkins-master","app.kubernetes.io/managed-by":"Helm","chart":"jenkins-acme-2.278.102","heritage":"Helm","release":"jenkins-acme-v2"},"name":"jenkins-role","namespace":"jenkins","selfLink":"/apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1/namespaces/jenkins/roles/jenkins-role","uid":"de5431f6-d576-4804-b132-6562d0ba7a94"},"rules":[{"apiGroups":["","extensions"],"resources":["*"],"verbs":["*"]},{"apiGroups":[""],"resources":["nodes"],"verbs":["get","list","watch","update"]}]}
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: jenkins-acme-v2
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: jenkins
  creationTimestamp: '2020-08-20T13:32:35Z'
  labels:
    app: jenkins-master
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    chart: jenkins-acme-2.278.102
    heritage: Helm
    release: jenkins-acme-v2
  name: jenkins-role
  namespace: jenkins
  resourceVersion: '94734324'
  selfLink: /apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1/namespaces/jenkins/roles/jenkins-role
  uid: de5431f6-d576-4804-b132-6562d0ba7a94
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ''
      - extensions
    resources:
      - '*'
    verbs:
      - '*'
  - apiGroups:
      - ''
    resources:
      - nodes
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
      - update
```

jenkins-deployer-role

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: jenkins-deployer-role
  namespace: jenkins
  selfLink: >-
    /apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1/namespaces/jenkins/roles/jenkins-deployer-role
  uid: 87b6486e-6576-11e8-92a9-06bdf97be268
  resourceVersion: '94731699'
  creationTimestamp: '2018-06-01T08:33:59Z'
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: >
      {"apiVersion":"rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1","kind":"Role","metadata":{"annotations":{},"creationTimestamp":"2018-06-01T08:33:59Z","name":"jenkins-deployer-role","namespace":"jenkins","selfLink":"/apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1/namespaces/jenkins/roles/jenkins-deployer-role","uid":"87b6486e-6576-11e8-92a9-06bdf97be268"},"rules":[{"apiGroups":[""],"resources":["pods"],"verbs":["*"]},{"apiGroups":[""],"resources":["deployments","services"],"verbs":["*"]}]}
rules:
  - verbs:
      - '*'
    apiGroups:
      - ''
    resources:
      - pods
  - verbs:
      - '*'
    apiGroups:
      - ''
    resources:
      - deployments
      - services
```

and jenkins-namespace-manager

```
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: jenkins-namespace-manager
  selfLink: /apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1/clusterroles/jenkins-namespace-manager
  uid: 93e80d54-6346-11e8-92a9-06bdf97be268
  resourceVersion: '94733699'
  creationTimestamp: '2018-05-29T13:45:41Z'
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: >
      {"apiVersion":"rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1","kind":"ClusterRole","metadata":{"annotations":{},"creationTimestamp":"2018-05-29T13:45:41Z","name":"jenkins-namespace-manager","selfLink":"/apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1/clusterroles/jenkins-namespace-manager","uid":"93e80d54-6346-11e8-92a9-06bdf97be268"},"rules":[{"apiGroups":[""],"resources":["namespaces"],"verbs":["get","watch","list","create"]},{"apiGroups":[""],"resources":["nodes"],"verbs":["get","list","watch","update"]}]}
rules:
  - verbs:
      - get
      - watch
      - list
      - create
    apiGroups:
      - ''
    resources:
      - namespaces
  - verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
      - update
    apiGroups:
      - ''
    resources:
      - nodes
```

and finally jenkins-deployer-role

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: >
      {"apiVersion":"rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1","kind":"ClusterRole","metadata":{"annotations":{},"creationTimestamp":"2018-05-29T13:29:43Z","name":"jenkins-deployer-role","selfLink":"/apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1/clusterroles/jenkins-deployer-role","uid":"58e1912e-6344-11e8-92a9-06bdf97be268"},"rules":[{"apiGroups":["","extensions","apps","rbac.authorization.k8s.io"],"resources":["*"],"verbs":["*"]},{"apiGroups":["policy"],"resources":["poddisruptionbudgets","podsecuritypolicies"],"verbs":["create","delete","deletecollection","patch","update","use","get"]},{"apiGroups":["","extensions","apps","rbac.authorization.k8s.io"],"resources":["nodes"],"verbs":["get","list","watch","update"]}]}
  creationTimestamp: '2018-05-29T13:29:43Z'
  name: jenkins-deployer-role
  resourceVersion: '94736572'
  selfLink: /apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1/clusterroles/jenkins-deployer-role
  uid: 58e1912e-6344-11e8-92a9-06bdf97be268
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ''
      - extensions
      - apps
      - rbac.authorization.k8s.io
    resources:
      - '*'
    verbs:
      - '*'
  - apiGroups:
      - policy
    resources:
      - poddisruptionbudgets
      - podsecuritypolicies
    verbs:
      - create
      - delete
      - deletecollection
      - patch
      - update
      - use
      - get
  - apiGroups:
      - ''
      - extensions
      - apps
      - rbac.authorization.k8s.io
    resources:
      - nodes
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
      - update
```

And the following bindings..

[Kubernetes bindings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFhGh.png)

I'm really stuck with this one, I don't want to give system:anonymous access to everything, although guess that could be an option.

The jenkins files which help build this are

JenkinsFile

```
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.FlowInterruptedException

def label = "worker-${UUID.randomUUID().toString()}"
def dockerRegistry = "id.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"
def localHelmRepository = "acme-helm"
def artifactoryHelmRepository = "https://acme.jfrog.io/acme/$localHelmRepository"
def jenkinsContext = "jenkins-staging"

def MAJOR = 2 // Change HERE
def MINOR = 278 // Change HERE
def PATCH = BUILD_NUMBER

def chartVersion = "X.X.X"
def name = "jenkins-acme"
def projectName = "$name"
def helmPackageName = "$projectName"
def helmReleaseName = "$name-v$MAJOR"
def fullVersion = "$MAJOR.$MINOR.$PATCH"
def jenkinsVersion = "${MAJOR}.${MINOR}" // Gets passed to Dockerfile for getting image from Docker hub



podTemplate(label: label, containers: [
        containerTemplate(name: 'docker', image: 'docker:18.05-dind', ttyEnabled: true, privileged: true),
        containerTemplate(name: 'perl', image: 'perl', ttyEnabled: true, command: 'cat'),
        containerTemplate(name: 'kubectl', image: 'lachlanevenson/k8s-kubectl:v1.18.8', command: 'cat', ttyEnabled: true),
        containerTemplate(name: 'helm', image: 'id.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/k8s-helm:3.2.0', command: 'cat', ttyEnabled: true),
        containerTemplate(name: 'clair-local-scan', image: '738398925563.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/clair-local-scan:latest', ttyEnabled: true, envVars: [envVar(key: 'DOCKER_HOST', value: 'tcp://localhost:2375')]),
        containerTemplate(name: 'clair-scanner', image: '738398925563.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/clair-scanner:latest', command: 'cat', ttyEnabled: true, envVars: [envVar(key: 'DOCKER_HOST', value: 'tcp://localhost:2375')]),
        containerTemplate(name: 'clair-db', image: "738398925563.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/clair-db:latest", ttyEnabled: true),
        containerTemplate(name: 'aws-cli', image: 'mesosphere/aws-cli', command: 'cat', ttyEnabled: true)
], volumes: [
        emptyDirVolume(mountPath: '/var/lib/docker')
]) {

    try {

        node(label) {
            def myRepo = checkout scm
            jenkinsUtils = load 'JenkinsUtil.groovy'

            stage('Set-Up and checks') {
                jenkinsContext = 'jenkins-staging'
                withCredentials([

                                 file(credentialsId: 'kubeclt-staging-config', variable: 'KUBECONFIG'),
                                 usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'jenkins_artifactory', usernameVariable: 'user', passwordVariable: 'password')]) {

                    jenkinsUtils.initKubectl(jenkinsUtils.appendToParams("kubectl", [
                            namespaces: ["jenkins"],
                            context   : jenkinsContext,
                            config    : KUBECONFIG])
                    )
                    jenkinsUtils.initHelm(jenkinsUtils.appendToParams("helm", [
                            namespace  : "jenkins",
                            helmRepo   : artifactoryHelmRepository,
                            username   : user,
                            password   : password,

                            ])
                    )
                }
            }

            stage('docker build and push') {
                container('perl'){
                    def JENKINS_HOST = "jenkins_api:1Ft38erDFjjfM6q3a6y7@jenkins.acme.com"
                    sh "curl -sSL \"https://${JENKINS_HOST}/pluginManager/api/xml?depth=1&xpath=/*/*/shortName|/*/*/version&wrapper=plugins\" | perl -pe 's/.*?<shortName>([\\w-]+).*?<version>([^<]+)()(<\\/\\w+>)+/\\1 \\2\\n/g'|sed 's/ /:/' > plugins.txt"
                    sh "cat plugins.txt"

                }

                container('docker'){
                    sh "ls -la"
                    sh "docker version"
                    // This is because of this annoying "feature" where the command ran from docker contains a \r character which must be removed
                    sh 'eval $(docker run --rm -t $(tty &>/dev/null && echo "-n") -v "$(pwd):/project" mesosphere/aws-cli ecr get-login --no-include-email --region eu-west-1 | tr \'\\r\' \' \')'




                    sh "sed \"s/JENKINS_VERSION/${jenkinsVersion}/g\" Dockerfile > Dockerfile.modified"
                    sh "cat Dockerfile.modified"
                    sh "docker build -t $name:$fullVersion -f Dockerfile.modified ."
                    sh "docker tag $name:$fullVersion $dockerRegistry/$name:$fullVersion"
                    sh "docker tag $name:$fullVersion $dockerRegistry/$name:latest"
                    sh "docker tag $name:$fullVersion $dockerRegistry/$name:${MAJOR}"
                    sh "docker tag $name:$fullVersion $dockerRegistry/$name:${MAJOR}.$MINOR"
                    sh "docker tag $name:$fullVersion $dockerRegistry/$name:${MAJOR}.${MINOR}.$PATCH"

                    sh "docker push $dockerRegistry/$name:$fullVersion"
                    sh "docker push $dockerRegistry/$name:latest"
                    sh "docker push $dockerRegistry/$name:${MAJOR}"
                    sh "docker push $dockerRegistry/$name:${MAJOR}.$MINOR"
                    sh "docker push $dockerRegistry/$name:${MAJOR}.${MINOR}.$PATCH"



                }
            }

            stage('helm build') {
                namespace = 'jenkins'
                jenkinsContext = 'jenkins-staging'
                withCredentials([
                                 file(credentialsId: 'kubeclt-staging-config', variable: 'KUBECONFIG'),
                                 usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'jenkins_artifactory', usernameVariable: 'user', passwordVariable: 'password')]) {

                    jenkinsUtils.setContext(jenkinsUtils.appendToParams("kubectl", [
                            context: jenkinsContext,
                            config : KUBECONFIG])
                    )

                    jenkinsUtils.helmDeploy(jenkinsUtils.appendToParams("helm", [
                            namespace  : namespace,
                            credentials: true,
                            release    : helmReleaseName,
                            args       : [replicaCount        : 1,
                                          imageTag            : fullVersion,
                                          namespace           : namespace,
                                          "MajorVersion"      : MAJOR]])
                    )

                    jenkinsUtils.helmPush(jenkinsUtils.appendToParams("helm", [
                            helmRepo   : artifactoryHelmRepository,
                            username   : user,
                            password   : password,
                            BuildInfo  : BRANCH_NAME,
                            Commit     : "${myRepo.GIT_COMMIT}"[0..6],
                            fullVersion: fullVersion
                    ]))
                }
            }

            stage('Deployment') {
                namespace = 'jenkins'
                jenkinsContext = 'jenkins-staging'
                withCredentials([

                                 file(credentialsId: 'kubeclt-staging-config', variable: 'KUBECONFIG')]) {
                    jenkinsUtils.setContext(jenkinsUtils.appendToParams("kubectl", [
                            context: jenkinsContext,
                            config : KUBECONFIG])
                    )

                    jenkinsUtils.helmDeploy(jenkinsUtils.appendToParams("helm", [
                            dryRun     : false,
                            namespace  : namespace,
                            package    : "${localHelmRepository}/${helmPackageName}",
                            credentials: true,

                            release    : helmReleaseName,
                            args       : [replicaCount        : 1,
                                          imageTag            : fullVersion,
                                          namespace           : namespace,
                                          "MajorVersion"      : MAJOR
                                          ]
                                        ])
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (FlowInterruptedException e) {
        def reasons = e.getCauses().collect { it.getShortDescription() }.join(",")
        println "Interupted. Reason: $reasons"
        currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
        return
    } catch (error) {
        println error
        throw error
    }
}
```

And the groovy file

```
templateMap = [
        "helm"   : [
                containerName: "helm",
                dryRun       : true,
                namespace    : "test",
                tag          : "xx",
                package      : "jenkins-acme",
                credentials  : false,
                ca_cert      : null,
                helm_cert    : null,
                helm_key     : null,
                args         : [
                majorVersion : 0,
                replicaCount : 1
                ]
        ],
        "kubectl": [
                containerName: "kubectl",
                context      : null,
                config       : null,
        ]
]

def appendToParams(String templateName, Map newArgs) {
    def copyTemplate = templateMap[templateName].clone()
    newArgs.each { paramName, paramValue ->
        if (paramName.equalsIgnoreCase("args"))
            newArgs[paramName].each {
                name, value -> copyTemplate[paramName][name] = value
            }
        else
            copyTemplate[paramName] = paramValue
    }
    return copyTemplate
}

def setContext(Map args) {
    container(args.containerName) {
        sh "kubectl --kubeconfig ${args.config} config use-context ${args.context}"
    }
}

def initKubectl(Map args) {
    container(args.containerName) {
        sh "kubectl --kubeconfig ${args.config} config use-context ${args.context}"

        for (namespace in args.namespaces)
            sh "kubectl -n $namespace get pods"
    }
}

def initHelm(Map args) {
    container(args.containerName) {
//        sh "helm init --client-only"

        def command = "helm version --short"
//        if (args.credentials)
//            command = "$command --tls --tls-ca-cert ${args.ca_cert} --tls-cert ${args.helm_cert} --tls-key ${args.helm_key}"
//
//        sh "$command  --tiller-connection-timeout 5 --tiller-namespace tiller-${args.namespace}"

        sh "helm repo add acme-helm ${args.helmRepo} --username ${args.username} --password ${args.password}"
        sh "helm repo update"
    }
}

def helmDeploy(Map args) {
    container(args.containerName) {

        sh "helm repo update"

        def command = "helm upgrade"

//        if (args.credentials)
//            command = "$command --tls --tls-ca-cert ${args.ca_cert} --tls-cert ${args.helm_cert} --tls-key ${args.helm_key}"

        if (args.dryRun) {
            sh "helm lint ${args.package}"
            command = "$command --dry-run --debug"
        }

//        command = "$command --install --tiller-namespace tiller-${args.namespace} --namespace ${args.namespace}"
        command = "$command --install --namespace ${args.namespace}"

        def setVar = "--set "
        args.args.each { key, value -> setVar = "$setVar$key=\"${value.toString().replace(",", "\\,")}\"," }
        setVar = setVar[0..-1]

        sh "$command $setVar --devel ${args.release} ${args.package}"
    }
}

def helmPush(Map args){
    container(args.containerName) {
        sh "helm package ${args.package} --version ${args.fullVersion} --app-version ${args.fullVersion}+${args.BuildInfo}-${args.Commit}"
        sh "curl -u${args.username}:${args.password} -T ${args.package}-${args.fullVersion}.tgz \"${args.helmRepo}/${args.package}-${args.fullVersion}.tgz\""
    }
}

return this
```

And from the log it seems to be when it runs

```
sh "kubectl --kubeconfig ${args.config} config use-context ${args.context}"
```

That it throws the error

```
io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Forbidden (user=system:anonymous, verb=get, resource=nodes, subresource=proxy)
```

but what permissions or roles should I change?

Many thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this section](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet-authentication-authorization/#kubelet-authentication) of the official kubernetes documentation and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54087124/11714114) provided by [Prafull Ladha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6843187/prafull-ladha):

> The above error means your apiserver doesn't have the credentials
> (`kubelet cert and key`) to authenticate the kubelet's log/exec
> commands and hence the  `Forbidden`  error message.
>
> You need to provide  `--kubelet-client-certificate=<path_to_cert>`
> and  `--kubelet-client-key=<path_to_key>`  to your apiserver, this way
> apiserver authenticate the kubelet with the certficate and key pair.

Very similar issue was also reported on **GitHub** in [this thread](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/55872), where you can find the following explanation:

> That means the api server has not been given a credential to use to
> authenticate to kubelets when proxying log/exec requests.
>
> See apiserver configuration as described in
> https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/kubelet-authentication-authorization/#kubelet-authentication